# Silverlight like login/register control in WPF

Tags: wpf

If you have created a silverlight business application you will see that in the top righthand corner on the menu is a login hyperlink.
Pressing it opens up a childwindow that displays a login control, within that control is another hyperlink that says "Register" if you press it, it flips the control 180 degrees around from the login control to the register control.

I really like this type of animation and want to do something similar in WPF for a project I am working on. However I am not sure how to do it, has anyone done this or knows where I can find some more information on how to achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D animations in Silverlight use `PlaneProjection`, which unfortunately doesn't exist in WPF. You can achieve a similar effect using WPF 3D.

Many pre-made solutions for flipping 3D planes are already available on the web. Some examples:

- [Thriple](http://thriple.codeplex.com/)
- [Planerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx)
- [FlipControl](http://flipcontrol.codeplex.com/)
- [Flippable Lists](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list)